# iPhone Page Control only shows on the first page of a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, pager

My page control only shows on the first page of the UIScrollView. Once I scroll to the next page it disappears.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Because I'm curious as to whether I need to add a subview of the page control each time I add a subview to my UIScrollView.

My relevant pieces of code:

```
-(IBAction)clickPageControl:(id)sender
{
    int page=pageControl.currentPage;
    CGRect frame=scroller.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width;
    pageControl.currentPage=page;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    arrayCount = [array count];
    scroller.delegate=self;
    scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
    scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;

    //should have an array of photo objects and the number of objects, correct?
    scrollWidth = 0;
    scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(arrayCount*scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount;i++) {
        PhotoViewController *pvc = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];        
        UIImageView *scrollImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(scroller.bounds, scrollWidth, 0)];
        CGRect rect = scrollImageView.frame;
        pvc.view.frame  = rect;
        [pvc view];
        pvc.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        id individualPhoto = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",individualPhoto);
        NSArray *keys=[individualPhoto allKeys];
        NSLog(@"%@",keys);
        NSString *imageURL=[individualPhoto objectForKey:@"source"];
        //here you can use this imageURL to get image-data and display it in imageView  
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
        NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        pvc.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        pvc.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo Number: %i", arrayCount];
        //check to make sure the proper URL was passed
        //I have an imageView next to the UIScrollView to test whether that works - it does.
        [scroller addSubview:pvc.view];
        [scrollImageView release];
        [pvc release];
        scrollWidth += scroller.frame.size.width;
    }

    if (arrayCount > 3) {
        pageControl.numberOfPages=3;
    } else {
    pageControl.numberOfPages=arrayCount;
    }
    pageControl.currentPage=0;
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];
}
```

Comment: Is the page control a subview of your scroll view?

Comment: No. This causes the page control to scroll with the content. Make it a sibling of the scrollview.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @omz - it works now. However, on a side note, I had to make the scrollview's background color clear. Because no matter the sibling order the scrollview always appeared on top of the page control. Is this because I'm calling `[self.view addSubview:scroller]` ... is that call even needed if I create it in IB? When I remove that and change the ScrollView's background back to black then the page control appears. I just want to confirm that page control wasn't appearing at first because I added the subview each time it loaded, is that correct?

Comment: btw, did you want to add your answer as an answer to the question so that I can give you credit and mark this question as answered?

Comment: `addSubview` shouldn't be needed if it's already in the nib file. It implicitly brings the view that's added to the front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not add your page control as a subview of the scroll view, this causes it to scroll with the content. Make it a sibling of the scroll view instead.